# Displaying product search results from amazon using python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, ui-automation, browser-automation

I am trying to implement a solution to display the products from a search result in ascending order. Here is what I have tried and able to achieve

1. I was able to print all the list of products from the search results
2. I converted the text into a list which looks like this - ['+2 colours/patterns', 'Sponsored', '2022 Apple iPhone SE (128 GB) - Starlight (3rd Generation)', '3', '$799', '00', 'FREE Delivery by Amazon', 'Temporarily out of stock.']
3. I have converted $799 into a integer and stripped of the first character $.

Now I can store all of these prices into an array and sort and display, but the problem is I need to print the product name as well along with it. I am just running out of ideas. Any suggestions?

Comment: Update the question with the text based HTML and your code trials.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
import pandas as pd

results=[]#You store the results here
for i in range(10):#Range as an example 
    #Here you append the results to the list
    results.append(['+2 colours/patterns', 'Sponsored', '2022 Apple iPhone SE (128 GB) - Starlight (3rd Generation)', '3', '$799', '00', 'FREE Delivery by Amazon', 'Temporarily out of stock.'])
#Here you structure the results
df=pd.DataFrame(results)
df.columns=["color","sponsored","product","something","price","something","something2","something3"]

#Here you print/store/whatever the results how you wanted:
df.apply(lambda i: print(i["product"],i["price"]),axis=1)
```